# counting how many times a name appears in a specific month

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating a score sheet in which I would like to count how many times a person played in a specific month. The formula will be on a separate tab/sheet. The table of data will look similar to this:

```
Month      Player1  Player2  Player3  Player4

January     Bob       Joe      Ed       John
January     Joe      Scott     Bob       Dan
January     Dan       John     Ed        Scott
February    Bob       Ed       Joe       Dan
February    Dan       John     Ed        Scott
February    John       Ed      Bob       Dan
```

I would like to count how many times Bob played in the month of January. This is the code I've tried and it counts only the first roll of my sheet. For example, I get the result of only "1" for Bob in the month of January.

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Scoreboard!$B$2:$H$282,MATCH(Scoreboard!$O2,ScoreBoard!$A$2:$A$282,0,),""&Names!R$5&"")
```

The "Names" tab will have all the players name and count the number of games played for the selected month. Cell "O2" is where I select which Month I want to see.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in columns **A** through **E**, in **G1** enter the month of interest.  In **H1** enter the name of interest.  The in another cell enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100=G1) * (B1:B100=H1))+SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100=G1) * (C1:C100=H1))+SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100=G1) * (D1:D100=H1))+SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100=G1) * (E1:E100=H1))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use a pivot table.

Comment: Thanks it works as needed. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Pivot tables but I will look into it in the near future.